# To update ios app when newer version is available

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am totally new to ios development. 
I have an ios7 and ios8 app which do polling to Server to check for latest version. 
Once the latest version of app is available I am opening Alert Box(Notification) for user to update App.

1. Now, once user click on Update Button, Which API I need to use to get latest version of App from Apple App Store or Web Store.
2. And how can I move the user's saved preferences to new App.

Will be helpful If some one can put code sample to do so.

Comment: why can't you rely on the App Store app to notify the user that a new version is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

Every App has a unique url in the App Store.

Lets assume you have updated your app from version 1.1 to 1.2 and releases app in app store.

Now in the application after checking your app version you can use openURL method to redirect to the url of App in app Store

e.g.

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"AppURL-String"]];

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's an API which you can call to update the app. The only option available is to send the user to the App Store page for your app where they will see the update button.

As far as preferences go if you're storing them in `NSUserDefaults` or as a plist then they should persist unless the user deletes the application from the device.